# MBP Powering Down When Idle

Tags: macbook-pro, power

My mid-2012 MacBookPro (Model 9,2) has developed an issue with power in the past few weeks. When it is left awake for several hours, but is idle, it powers off. When I turn it back on and log in, it does not give the typical message about being shut down unexpectedly.

I have noticed this in clamshell mode with lots of USB devices and an external monitor attached as well as when it is left open, but told not to sleep in the Energy Saver Preference Panel.

It always happens when left on over night and today happened after it was left idle for about 2 hours.

The problem has just started happening, but I cannot remember if it started right after I upgraded to 10.10.2 or not.

pm -g assertions reads:

> 2015-02-15 18:28:53 -0500
>
> Assertion status system-wide:
>
> BackgroundTask                 0
>
> ApplePushServiceTask           0
>
> UserIsActive                   1
>
> PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
>
> PreventSystemSleep             0
>
> ExternalMedia                  0
>
> PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
>
> NetworkClientActive            0
>
> Listed by owning process:
>
> pid 77(hidd): [0x00003f3700090493] 00:03:01 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle"
>
> Timeout will fire in 579 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
>
> Kernel Assertions: 0x100=MAGICWAKE
>
> id=504  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=12/31/69, 7:00 PM description=en1 owner=en1

Console reads:

> 2/15/15 11:41:31.035 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:42:51.403 AM apsd[56]: Peer [pid=315] requested push wake but lacks APSPushWakeEntitlement
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.000 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.023 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.030 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.049 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.165 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.175 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 11:43:18.191 AM apsd[56]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 1:57:51.088 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 1:59:29.210 PM apsd[57]: Peer [pid=308] requested push wake but lacks APSPushWakeEntitlement
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:00.378 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:01.671 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:01.728 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:02.530 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:02.872 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:04.988 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 2:00:05.873 PM apsd[57]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
>
> 2/15/15 6:25:52.861 PM WindowServer[148]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [16183433498438]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake

Comment: what does your "pmset -g assertions" says

Comment: also in the Console, the lines before the wake reason

Comment: Thanks, nice work ! now lets see why your PreventSystemSleep 0 (is set to zero, it should be 1), by using the syst pref energy saver set to computer sleep - Newer !

Comment: Computer sleep is "never". Display sleep is 10  minutes